# Appium : Original error: -[XCUIElement resolve]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: appium, appium-ios, xcode11

Please find config i am using as below

Xcode : 11 GM Seed
Appium : 1.14.2
Real Device : iPhone 7 (12.4.1)

I have updated my Xcode to 11 Because of the xcode 10.3 doesn’t support iOS 12.4.1.

After upgrading it started giving an error

Original error: -[XCUIElement resolve]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

App is getting launched but nothing happens after that and i can see above error in my appium console.

Comment: I'm facing this same issue, however my IOS device is on IOS 13.1
I have tried the following 
- IOS 13.1 x Xcode 10.3 - Tests show that IOS 13.1 may be incompatible with Xcode version, and asked me to update it
- IOS 13.1 x Xcode 11  - Face the above error, so now I'm stuck

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't need to downgrade Xcode if using Appium 1.15.0:

`$ npm install -g appium@1.15.0`

My device's iOS is 12.4.1, I have both 11 and 10.3 Xcode's.

When I used Appium Desktop 1.13.0, I launched WDA by opening it's Xcode project ( in Xcode 10.3 ) and started testing WRA-Runner target ( CMD + U ).
Then I ran

`$ python -m unittest my_ui_test.py`

Now with Appium 1.15.0 I just run:

`$ appium`

and then

`$ python -m unittest my_ui_test.py`

from another terminal tab.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Got this error after updating appium to v1.15:
Project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file.

Comment: @NoorYeaserKhan Did you try to open WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj ?

Comment: Yes, I've observed this error message after trying to open the WebdriverAgent.xcodeproj file.

Comment: @NoorYeaserKhan Well, I don't see the need to open and launch `WDA` when using Appium v.15. I suppose it's installed automatically to your device.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue here. ios:13.1. I have tried on the 12.4.1 iphone but got the same issue xcode: 10.3

please share the solution

Answer (score 1):

I try and it works on IOS simulator and real devices

Install appium Appium v1.15.0-rc.5 via nmp

```
Xcode 11.
IOS 13
========
install webdriveragent via path *node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent* ==> appium had been update
```

ref https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13288#issuecomment-535574619

Answer (score 0):

Have you reinstalled your WebDriverAgent? Provide your code that sends commands to the WDA, probably you are using wrong type of selectors.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I have found a solution on my own, i have downloaded a patch file for iOS 12.4.1 and ran using Xcode 10.3 and its working now.....:)

Comment: @ManishBoricha could you provide a little more information around your solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Vault23 I have the same problem, my code is here: https://gist.github.com/gatamar/ee3a6838fa0b0012a654abe1afafca1f#file-test_should_find_elements_by_accessibility_id-py . I'm going to try 10.3 as  author did.

Comment: @OlhaPavliuk xcode 10.3 is the most stable version in terms of testing with appium. i would recommend you to downgrade xcode for that version

Comment: @zypherman For the support file you can go to this link https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport
And as Xcode 11 is officially launched so you can install it and run the automation on all the devices till iOS 13.0

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue as well after updating to xcode 11, all my tests were failing with this error on simulator with OS 13 and lower, the fix eventually was to upgrade to appium 1.15. Use the npm install -g appium@1.15.0 command.
No other maintenance or workarounds needed

Answer (score 0):

It works in my macbook pro.

Env:
- Xcode 11.1
- iOS 13

How:
- Update appium from 1.15.0 to 1.15.
- Remove WebDriverAgent app and test app

Appium commiter said if we update appium, the best way is clean env by removing WebDriverAgent etc.

See also: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/13274